# How tell memtest to use memory on specific range on start?

Tags: memtest86+, memtest

I launch memtest and got it holding during tests. I guess that memtest uses bad memory blocks when it started. Is there a way to shift this memory range? For example, memtest loaded and take memory range from 0x000, but can I launch it from memory range 0x0ff?

Please note that that question is not about test some memory ranges but launch UI on safe memory addresses

Comment: What's the point if the RAM is bad? Process of elimination to figure out which stick it is, just insert & test each individually. Discard the failed one.

Comment: Although my money here is on the DIMM itself, don't forget to consider memory slots themselves while doing the DIMM test shuffle. If you have just one and it fails, move it to another slot and test again. If it checks out in the second slot you may want to stop using the other one.

Comment: @MiG - or in an extreme situation… I was once testing a machine with 8 sticks of ECC RAM, sitting on 2 separate riser cards. Not only was one stick bad, but one of the riser cards was also failing. That took one *heck* of a lot of iterations to figure out what the entire issue was. ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Been there with PATA drives, cables and connectors...